# legitimacy of the tasks in the task scheduler

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, powershell, task-scheduler

Is there a way to know the source and legitimacy of the tasks in the task scheduler in windows server 2008 and 2003? Can I check if the task was added by Microsoft (ie: from sccm) or by a 3rd party application?

For each task in the task scheduler, I want to verify that the task has not been created by a third party application. I only want to allow standards Microsoft Tasks and disable all other non-standards tasks.

I have created a PowerShell script that goes through all the xml files in the C:\Windows\System32\Tasks directory and I was able to read all the xml task files successfully but I am stuck on how to validate the tasks.

Here is the script for your reference:

```
Function TaskSniper()
{
   #Getting all the fils in the Tasks folder
   $files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks" -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer};
   [Xml] $StandardXmlFile = Get-Content "Edit Me";

   foreach($file in $files)
   {
       #constructing the file path
       $path = $file.DirectoryName + "\" + $file.Name 

       #reading the file as an XML doc
       [Xml] $xmlFile = Get-Content $path


       #DS SEE: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/caa8422f-6397-4510-ba6e-e28f2d2ee0d2/
       #(get-authenticodesignature C:\Windows\System32\appidpolicyconverter.exe).status -eq "valid"

       #Display something
       $xmlFile.Task.Settings.Hidden

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Legitimacy sounds vague.

If by source you are referring to the Author, that is available in the Principals node:

```
$xmlFile.Task.Principals.ChildNodes

id                                      GroupId                                 RunLevel
--                                      -------                                 --------
Author                                  S-1-5-32-545                            LeastPrivilege
```

An alternative approach may be to audit when and who creates a scheduled task.  Hera are the Security event id's for Windows 2008 R2:

```
4698    A scheduled task was created.
4700    A scheduled task was enabled.
4702    A scheduled task was updated.
```